# Terminal does not accept some typed-in unicode characters

Tags: xterm, unicode, xmodmap, rxvt

I need to troubleshoot why typing in some unicode characters in my terminal won’t work.

I use a non-qwerty keyboard layout (namely [neo](http://www.neo-layout.org/)) which allows me to directly type in unicode characters such as `α β γ δ … ∀ ∃ … ∘ ⇒ ⇔`, which works just fine for most applications.

However with terminals such as `rxvt-unicode` or `xterm`, typing in the characters `∘` and `⇔` does nothing – *although the characters are displayed perfectly well* when I copy-paste them.

Information on the specific characters and keys which don’t work:

- [`⇔`](http://unicodelookup.com/#%D4/1): hex code `0x21D4`; neo-sequence: `Capslock + AltGr + m`
- [`∘`](http://unicodelookup.com/#%18/1): hex code: `0x2218`; neo-sequence: `Capslock + AltGr + [`

Other characters typed in via `Capslock + AltGr + ⟨some key⟩`, for instance `⇒`, also work without problem on my terminal. This baffles me.

> So does anyone know where the problem might lie here? Does anyone have a clue where to look?

I use Parabola GNU/Linux (which is basically Arch Linux).

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I at least found a work-around now.

It turns out the problem is that `ifonlyif` and `jot` do not seem to be recognised by `xmodmap` as keysymnames. They are used in my configuration.

```
$ xmodmap -pke | egrep "jot|ifonlyif" 
keycode  34 = ssharp U1E9E ssharp U1E9E U017F Greek_finalsmallsigma U2212 NoSymbol jot NoSymbol U017F Greek_finalsmallsigma U2212 NoSymbol jot
keycode  58 = m M m M percent Greek_mu KP_1 KP_1 ifonlyif
```

If one replaces them by their unicode hex codes, all works well. So I just did:

```
$ xmodmap -pke | sed -e 's:ifonlyif:U21D4:' -e 's:jot:U2218:' > .Xmodmap
$ xmodmap .Xmodmap
$ xmodmap -pke | egrep "keycode  (34|58)" 
keycode  34 = ssharp U1E9E ssharp U1E9E U017F Greek_finalsmallsigma U2212 NoSymbol U2218 NoSymbol U017F Greek_finalsmallsigma U2212
keycode  58 = m M m M percent Greek_mu KP_1 KP_1 U21D4
```

---

In case this might be helpful for others, I came to this by the following: I observed the `xev` output for trying to type in `⇔` (ifonlyif) and `∘` (jot) respectively.

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2400001,
    root 0x9b, subw 0x0, time 170075495, (1,1), root:(552,302),
    state 0xa0, keycode 58 (keysym 0x8cd, ifonlyif), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2400001,
    root 0x9b, subw 0x0, time 170075574, (1,1), root:(552,302),
    state 0xa0, keycode 58 (keysym 0x8cd, ifonlyif), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2400001,
    root 0x9b, subw 0x0, time 170076304, (1,1), root:(552,302),
    state 0xa0, keycode 34 (keysym 0xbca, jot), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2400001,
    root 0x9b, subw 0x0, time 170076336, (1,1), root:(552,302),
    state 0xa0, keycode 34 (keysym 0xbca, jot), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

In contrast, typing in other, working characters (`Θ`, `⇒`) give lines such as:

```
…
state 0xa0, keycode 61 (keysym 0x7c8, Greek_THETA), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 2 bytes: (ce 98) "Θ"

…
state 0xa0, keycode 59 (keysym 0x10021d2, U21D2), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 3 bytes: (e2 87 92) "⇒"
```

So I knew the problem possibly was `XLookupString` failing to return anything. So I did `man xlookupstring` and `man xmodmap`. Then I investigated the xmodmap table `xmodmap -pke` and compared the failing lookup of `ifonlyif` as `⇔` with the successfull lookup of `U21D2` as `⇒`.